# How to handle webservice without WSDL with C#?

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, web-services, c#-4.0

My application(.NET 4.0) needs to integrate with a webservice. If the webservice did have a WSDL it would be easy to generate proxy class with WCF but this is not possible in this case (No WSDL).

To communicate with this server we will have to send a message with settings and then receiver something like this :

```
<Desc>
<Make cfe_code="98" cfe_value="Volkswagen" label="Märke" value="Volkswagen"/>
<ModelName cfe_code="99" cfe_value="Touareg" label="Modell" value="Touareg"/>
<BodyType cfe_code="212" cfe_value="22" label="Kaross" value="SUV"/>
<ModelYear cfe_code="8" cfe_value="2005" label="Årsmodell" value="2005"/>
...
</Desc>
```

So how do I solve this? Do I have to dig in to XMLDocuments and do it all manual?

**Edit1:** The URL to the webservice might look like this : http://MyServer.com/ag/get?UID=9999999999.eu_vddsall_xml&VINREG=STU123&LANG=en

```
UID is static
VINREG is the registration ID of the object that we need information about
LANG is the language setting
```

There will also be a basic authentication (Username/Password)

Comment: I guess so.  We need more information.  Why is there no WSDL?  What methods does this service expose?

Comment: @Inuyasha > I don´t know why there is no WSDL. There is only one method, look at the Edit1.

Comment: @SnowJim - Have you tried hitting the service's address and adding ?wsdl to the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a non-SOAP endpoint, in which case there is not a standard way to expose service metadata via a WSDL.

Essentially what you'd need to do is create classes to represent the `Desc` and its child elements:

```
[XmlRoot("Desc")]
public class Description
{

    [XmlElement("Make")]
    public Make make { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ModelName")]
    public ModelName modelName { get; set; }

    // etc...
}

public class Make
{

    [XmlAttribute("cfe_code")]
    public int cfeCode { get; set; }

    // etc...
}
```

These classes represent the data you will receive from the service call.  Next, create a `ServiceContract` that represents the service method:

```
[ServiceContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
      UriTemplate = "get?UID=9999.eu_vddsall_xml&VINREG={vinreg}&LANG=en")]
    Description MyMethod(string vinreg);
}
```

Lastly, create an instance of a client proxy using IChannelFactory and consume the service.

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/04/21/how-to-consume-rest-services-with-wcf.aspx) on how to create a WCF client to consume a RESTful service using a WCF client.

Comment: FYI, `[Serializable]` is ignored by the XML Serializer.

Comment: @John Saunders - I wasn't sure if the Serializable attribute was needed or not, so I erred on the side of caution. Thanks for the clarification.  I've edited my post to remove the unnecessary attribute.

Comment: @RoccoC5 > This looks nice! Thanks! I will try to get this working as soon as possible.